# install opencv2.0 on Ubuntu8.10 missing libunicap, libucil and libv4l1

Tags: installation

Basically, I am trying to build opencv 2.0 via CMake on Ubuntu 8.10. It keeps saying libunicap, libucil and libv4l1 are missing on my system. I searched for the packages for these libraries on places like Synaptic Package Manager but found none except that on http://packages.ubuntu.com there are some similar ones like libunicap2 libucil2 , which cannot be installed on my Ubuntu due to "installation error: Dependency is not satisfiable".

Here is the missing library info reported by CMake:

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE\_BUILD\_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE\_INSTALL\_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD\_PYTHON\_SUPPORT=ON ..   
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 43  
-- checking for module 'libunicap'  
--   package 'libunicap' not found  
-- checking for module 'libucil'  
--   package 'libucil' not found  
-- checking for module 'libv4l1'  
--   package 'libv4l1' not found  
-- IPP detected:   
-- Parsing 'cvconfig.h.cmake'  
running mkdir -p "/home/tim/program_files/tim/OpenCV-2.0.0/release/unix-install/"  2>&1  
--   
-- General configuration for opencv 2.0.0 =====================================  
--   
--     Compiler:            
--     C++ flags (Release):     -Wall -pthread -ffunction-sections  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -ffast-math -mmmx -DNDEBUG   
--     C++ flags (Debug):       -Wall -pthread -ffunction-sections  -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG   
--     Linker flags (Release):       
--     Linker flags (Debug):         
--   
--   GUI:   
--     GTK+ 2.x:          1  
--     GThread:           1  
--   
--   Image I/O:   
--     JPEG:              TRUE  
--     PNG:               TRUE  
--     TIFF:              TRUE  
--     JASPER:            TRUE  
--   
--   Video I/O:   
--     DC1394 1.x:          
--     DC1394 2.x:        1  
--     FFMPEG:            1  
--       codec:           1  
--       format:          1  
--       util:            1  
--       swscale:         1  
--       gentoo-style:          
--     GStreamer:         1  
--     UniCap:              
--     V4L/V4L2:          1/1  
--     Xine:              1  
--   
--   Interfaces:   
--     Old Python:        0  
--     Python:            ON  
--     Use IPP:           NO  
--     Build Documentation    0  
--   
--     Install path:          /usr/local  
--   
--     cvconfig.h is in:      /home/tim/program_files/tim/OpenCV-2.0.0/release  
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------  
--   
-- Configuring done  
-- Generatim done  
-- Build files have been written to: /home/tim/program_files/tim/OpenCV-2.0.0/release
```

I also tried to install the pre-required libraries specified for earlier version of OpenCV, which I found online, but found they are already installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libjpeg62-dev libtiff4-dev     
Reading package lists... Done     
Building dependency tree            
Reading state information... Done     
libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version.     
libavcodec-dev is already the newest version.     
libavformat-dev is already the newest version.     
libjpeg62-dev is already the newest version.     
libtiff4-dev is already the newest version.     
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:     
  dnsmasq-base ttf-liberation     
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.     
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

So I am puzzled. Anyone can give some advice please?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately there are no unicap and ucil packages for ubuntu hardy. This does not mean that you can not compile and use openCV-2.0 in your applications but only that you will miss the functionalities offered by these specific libraries.

After running cmake you just have to compile and install OpenCV using:

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

from the same directory where you executed cmake.

Then you can compile and link your applications with OpenCV following the infos in the last section of the INSTALL file.